# Azure AD Microsoft Identity Web OpenIdConnectEvents - How to access optional claims from the user token during sign out

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, claims-based-identity, .net-core-3.1

Using Net Core 3.1 with Microsoft Identity Web and Azure AD.

I'm trying to setup some logging for when a user signs in and out of my web app project. The logging needs to include details of the user as well as the IP Address of the client endpoint they used during sign in and sign out. I then pass the IP Address through an extension method for capturing Geo Location info that is added to the log event for that user authentication.

In startup.cs I have configured some extended options for the OpenIdConnectOptions, they are:

- OnTokenValidated
- OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut
- OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect

The OpenIdEvents class I created is just simply to move away the methods from the startup.cs file for cleanliness.

Extract from startup.cs below:

```
// Create a new instance of the class that stores the methods called
// by OpenIdConnectEvents(); i.e. when a user logs in or out the app.
// See section below :- 'services.Configure'
OpenIdEvents openIdEvents = new OpenIdEvents();

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
    // Advanced config - capturing user events. See OpenIdEvents class.
    options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
    options.Events.OnTokenValidated += openIdEvents.OnTokenValidatedFunc;
    // This is event is fired when the user is redirected to the MS Signout Page (before they've physically signed out)
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut += openIdEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc;
    // DO NOT DELETE - May use in the future.
    // OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect doesn't produce any claims to read for the user after they have signed out.
    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect += openIdEvents.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirectFunc;
 });
```

So far I have found a solution to capture the required claims of the user for when they sign in, the 'TokenValidatedContext' passed to the first method 'OnTokenValidatedFunc' contains details of the security token which in itself shows the optional claims that I had configured including the IP Address (referred to as "ipaddr")

Some of these optional claims were configured in the App manifest file in Azure, they are present in the security token in this first method so pretty sure Azure is setup correctly.

Extract from Azure App Manifest File:

```
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "family_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "given_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "ipaddr",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
```

'OnTokenValidatedFunc' method shown below:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when an IdToken has been validated and produced an AuthenticationTicket.
        /// See weblink: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.ontokenvalidated?view=aspnetcore-3.0
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task OnTokenValidatedFunc(TokenValidatedContext context)
        {
            var token = context.SecurityToken;
            var userId = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "oid").Value;
            var givenName = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "given_name").Value;
            var familyName = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "family_name").Value;
            var userName = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "preferred_username").Value;
            string ipAddress = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "ipaddr").Value;

            GeoHelper geoHelper = new GeoHelper();
            var geoInfo = await geoHelper.GetGeoInfo(ipAddress);

            string logEventCategory = "Open Id Connect";
            string logEventType = "User Login";
            string logEventSource = "WebApp_RAZOR";
            string logCountry = "";
            string logRegionName = "";
            string logCity = "";
            string logZip = "";
            string logLatitude = "";
            string logLongitude = "";
            string logIsp = "";
            string logMobile = "";
            string logUserId = userId;
            string logUserName = userName;
            string logForename = givenName;
            string logSurname = familyName;
            string logData = "User login";

            if (geoInfo != null)
            {
                logCountry = geoInfo.Country;
                logRegionName = geoInfo.RegionName;
                logCity = geoInfo.City;
                logZip = geoInfo.Zip;
                logLatitude = geoInfo.Latitude.ToString();
                logLongitude = geoInfo.Longitude.ToString();
                logIsp = geoInfo.Isp;
                logMobile = geoInfo.Mobile.ToString();
            }

            // Tested on 31/08/2020
            Log.Information(
                "{@LogEventCategory}" +
                "{@LogEventType}" +
                "{@LogEventSource}" +
                "{@LogCountry}" +
                "{@LogRegion}" +
                "{@LogCity}" +
                "{@LogZip}" +
                "{@LogLatitude}" +
                "{@LogLongitude}" +
                "{@LogIsp}" +
                "{@LogMobile}" +
                "{@LogUserId}" +
                "{@LogUsername}" +
                "{@LogForename}" +
                "{@LogSurname}" +
                "{@LogData}",
                logEventCategory,
                logEventType,
                logEventSource,
                logCountry,
                logRegionName,
                logCity,
                logZip,
                logLatitude,
                logLongitude,
                logIsp,
                logMobile,
                logUserId,
                logUserName,
                logForename,
                logSurname,
                logData);

            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

See Debug shots below:

[image]

When expanding the claims, you can see the claim for "ipaddr" is shown:

[image]

**MY ISSUE:**

The other event types fired from OpenIdConnectEvents for when the user signs out, does not function in the same way and this is where I am stuck!

There are two different event types I have tried testing with:

- OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut
- OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect

Each one is fired at a slightly different point during the user sign out process i.e. the 'OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc' is fired when the user is being re-directed to the Microsoft Sign Out page, just before they actually hit the button and sign out.

This is not an ideal event type to work with given the user could abort signing out of the application and the log generated would not reflect this, however I have so far found that I could at least access most of the claims of the user, BUT the "ipaddr" claim is not listed and I simply don't know why or how to get it.

When I look at the Debug info I find the security token is not shown at all and the only way to access the user claims was to read another part of the context by navigating to context.HttpContext.User.Claims

Debug Screenshot:

[image]

The method for this shown below:

```
        public async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc(RedirectContext context)
        {
            var user = context.HttpContext.User;
            string ipAddress = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "ipaddr").Value;
            var userId = user.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            var givenName = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
            var familyName = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;
            var userName = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
            
            // The IP Address claim is missing!
            //string ipAddress = claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "ipaddr").Value;

            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

The above method only gives a partial solution given I still need the IP Address claim but is not present at all, but the choice in using this event type as explained above is not ideal anyway.

AND FINALLY:

Trying to subscribe to the final option 'OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect' has been a complete waste of time so far given none of the user claims are present at all in the context. It seems that Microsoft dumps them once the user has hit the Sign out button and returned back to the 'Signed Out' page in the web app.

Really I want a solution for when the user has actually signed out, not half way through the process of signing out, BUT I must be able access the user claims including the IP Address which is not present in either of the above two events fired during this process.

All I want is to simply capture the details (claims) of the user and the IP Address of the client session they are connecting from and log this when they sign in and sign out of the web application. Is this really too much to ask!

Documentation on this is very sparse, I would much appreciate some clues from anyone out there who understands well how MS Identity Web and OpenIDConnect Events function behind the scenes.

Solution 1 = Being able to access the IP Address claim from the context during 'OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut' but it is currently missing...

Solution 2 (Preferred) = Being able to access the user claims during 'OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect' but currently none of them are listed at all.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi @OJB1, Your question is big an if my understanding was correct you can store the climes in to a variable instead of directly getting from a method.

Comment: Hi, I need to be able to access the claims from the user once they have signed out of the application using one of two possible events that are generated from OpenIdConnect. Neither of these two events I have tested with so far have given all the information that is needed.

Comment: I am struggling to implement `OpenIdConnectOptions` with `Microsoft.Identity.Web`.  Did you implement something custom for a `IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>` service?

Comment: Nope, OpenIdConnectOptions was just part of the baked in library extensions with Microsoft.Identity.Web, I didn't do anything special to make use of it. In the end I didnt achieve what i really wanted in my question. I ended up just grabbing the details of the user context through OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc method and then used a separate GeoHelper class to fetch then IP Address of the destination where the person was when singing out (or should we say was about to sign out! :(

Comment: Thanks.  Strange that the `OpenIdConnectEvents` are not triggered for me at all.

Comment: OpenIdConnectEvents might not be triggered if the user is already signed-in (session cookie exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments above, and also taking on board Jean-Marc Prieur's comments above on the fact that no claims will ever be present once the user has completely signed out, I  ended up just grabbing the details of the user context through OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc method and then used a separate GeoHelper class to fetch the IP Address of the destination where the person was when singing out (or should we say was about to sign out!

Yes appreciate this isn't the most ideal cause & affect, but to be honest it's not going to present an big issue for me and may not for others given in most cases, logging when someone signs out is not business critical, its more to get a idea of system usage. By the time someone has reached the MS popup page to logout, we should likely assume 99% of cases that they will proceed and actually logout.

So below is the code I used to achieve the above scenario:

startup.cs class (extract from startup.cs code bloat)

```
// Create a new instance of the class that stores the methods called
// by OpenIdConnectEvents(); i.e. when a user logs in or out the app.
// See section below :- 'services.Configure'
OpenIdEvents openIdEvents = new OpenIdEvents();

// The following lines code instruct the asp.net core middleware to use the data in the "roles" claim in the Authorize attribute and User.IsInrole()
// See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2 for more info.

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
    // Advanced config - capturing user events. See OpenIdEvents class.
    options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
    options.Events.OnTokenValidated += openIdEvents.OnTokenValidatedFunc;
    // This is event is fired when the user is redirected to the MS Signout Page (before they've physically signed out)
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut += openIdEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc;
    // DO NOT DELETE - May use in the future.
    // OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect doesn't produce any user claims to read from for the user after they have signed out.
    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect += openIdEvents.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirectFunc;
});
```

My custom class for the Geolocation:

```
namespace MyProject.Classes.GeoLocation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// See weblink for API documentation: https://ip-api.com/docs or https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json
    /// Note: Not free for commercial use - fee plan during development only!
    /// Sample query: http://ip-api.com/json/{ip_address}?fields=status,message,country,countryCode,region,regionName,city,zip,lat,lon,isp,mobile,query
    /// </summary>
    public class GeoHelper
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public GeoHelper()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient()
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
            };
        }

        public async Task<GeoInfo> GetGeoInfo(string ip)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"http://ip-api.com/json/{ip}?fields=status,message,country,countryCode,region,regionName,city,zip,lat,lon,isp,mobile,query");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoInfo>(json);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Do nothing, just return null.
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

OpenIdEvents.cs class:

```
namespace MyProject.Classes.Security
{
    public class OpenIdEvents
    {
        // Create the concurrent dictionary to store the user's IP Addresss when they sign in, the value is fetched
        // from the dictionary when they sing out. given this information is not present within the contect passed through the event.
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> IpAddressDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when an IdToken has been validated and produced an AuthenticationTicket.
        /// See weblink: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.ontokenvalidated?view=aspnetcore-3.0
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task OnTokenValidatedFunc(TokenValidatedContext context)
        {
            var token = context.SecurityToken;
            var userId = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "oid").Value;
            var givenName = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "given_name").Value;
            var familyName = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "family_name").Value;
            var username = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "preferred_username").Value;
            var ipAddress = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "ipaddr").Value;
            // Add the IP Address from the user's ID Token to the dictionary, we will remove
            // it from the dictionary when the user requests a sign out through OpenIDConnect. 
            IpAddressDictionary.TryAdd(userId, ipAddress);

            GeoHelper geoHelper = new GeoHelper();
            var geoInfo = await geoHelper.GetGeoInfo(ipAddress);

            string logEventCategory = "Open Id Connect";
            string logEventType = "User Sign In";
            string logEventSource = "MyProject";
            string logCountry = "";
            string logRegionName = "";
            string logCity = "";
            string logZip = "";
            string logLatitude = "";
            string logLongitude = "";
            string logIsp = "";
            string logMobile = "";
            string logUserId = userId;
            string logUserName = username;
            string logForename = givenName;
            string logSurname = familyName;
            string logData = "User with username [" + username + "] forename [" + givenName + "] surname [" + familyName + "] from IP Address [" + ipAddress + "] signed into the application [MyProject] Succesfully";

            if (geoInfo != null)
            {
                logCountry = geoInfo.Country;
                logRegionName = geoInfo.RegionName;
                logCity = geoInfo.City;
                logZip = geoInfo.Zip;
                logLatitude = geoInfo.Latitude.ToString();
                logLongitude = geoInfo.Longitude.ToString();
                logIsp = geoInfo.Isp;
                logMobile = geoInfo.Mobile.ToString();
            }

            // Tested on 31/08/2020
            Log.Information(
                "{@LogEventCategory}" +
                "{@LogEventType}" +
                "{@LogEventSource}" +
                "{@LogCountry}" +
                "{@LogRegion}" +
                "{@LogCity}" +
                "{@LogZip}" +
                "{@LogLatitude}" +
                "{@LogLongitude}" +
                "{@LogIsp}" +
                "{@LogMobile}" +
                "{@LogUserId}" +
                "{@LogUsername}" +
                "{@LogForename}" +
                "{@LogSurname}" +
                "{@LogData}",
                logEventCategory,
                logEventType,
                logEventSource,
                logCountry,
                logRegionName,
                logCity,
                logZip,
                logLatitude,
                logLongitude,
                logIsp,
                logMobile,
                logUserId,
                logUserName,
                logForename,
                logSurname,
                logData);

            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked before redirecting to the identity provider to sign out.
        /// See weblink: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onredirecttoidentityproviderforsignout?view=aspnetcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.1
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc(RedirectContext context)
        {
            var user = context.HttpContext.User;
            var userId = user.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            var givenName = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
            var familyName = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;
            var username = user.Identity.Name;

            string logEventCategory = "Open Id Connect";
            string logEventType = "User Sign Out";
            string logEventSource = "MyProject";
            string logCountry = "";
            string logRegionName = "";
            string logCity = "";
            string logZip = "";
            string logLatitude = "";
            string logLongitude = "";
            string logIsp = "";
            string logMobile = "";
            string logUserId = userId;
            string logUserName = username;
            string logForename = givenName;
            string logSurname = familyName;

            IpAddressDictionary.TryRemove(userId, out string ipAddress);

            if (ipAddress != null)
            {
                // Re-fetch the geo-location details which may be different than the login session
                // given the user might have been signed in using a cell phone and move locations.
                GeoHelper geoHelper = new GeoHelper();
                var geoInfo = await geoHelper.GetGeoInfo(ipAddress);

                if (geoInfo != null)
                {
                    logCountry = geoInfo.Country;
                    logRegionName = geoInfo.RegionName;
                    logCity = geoInfo.City;
                    logZip = geoInfo.Zip;
                    logLatitude = geoInfo.Latitude.ToString();
                    logLongitude = geoInfo.Longitude.ToString();
                    logIsp = geoInfo.Isp;
                    logMobile = geoInfo.Mobile.ToString();
                }
            }

            string logData = "User with username [" + username + "] forename [" + givenName + "] surname [" + familyName + "] from IP Address [" + ipAddress + "] signed out the application [MyProject] Succesfully";

            // Tested on 31/08/2020
            Log.Information(
                "{@LogEventCategory}" +
                "{@LogEventType}" +
                "{@LogEventSource}" +
                "{@LogCountry}" +
                "{@LogRegion}" +
                "{@LogCity}" +
                "{@LogZip}" +
                "{@LogLatitude}" +
                "{@LogLongitude}" +
                "{@LogIsp}" +
                "{@LogMobile}" +
                "{@LogUserId}" +
                "{@LogUsername}" +
                "{@LogForename}" +
                "{@LogSurname}" +
                "{@LogData}",
                logEventCategory,
                logEventType,
                logEventSource,
                logCountry,
                logRegionName,
                logCity,
                logZip,
                logLatitude,
                logLongitude,
                logIsp,
                logMobile,
                logUserId,
                logUserName,
                logForename,
                logSurname,
                logData);

            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked before redirecting to the SignedOutRedirectUri at the end of a remote sign-out flow.
        /// See weblink: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onsignedoutcallbackredirect?view=aspnetcore-3.0
        /// Not currently in use becuase neither the user's ID Token or claims were present. We had to use the above method instead.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task OnSignedOutCallbackRedirectFunc(RemoteSignOutContext context)
        {

            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to be able to access the claims from the user once they have signed out of the application using one of two possible events that are generated from OpenIdConnect

The user signed out at that point. He/She is no longer there, so it makes sense it has no claims, it's going back to the default, empty anonymous user because it's signed out.